# Linux Sleep Command - Sleep less than 1 ms

Tags: linux, command, sleep

How can I sleep less than 0.001s / 1ms?

If I use this, it shows me that is is only sleeping for 1ms. Is it possible to sleep less?

```bash
$ time sleep 0.00001
sleep 0.00001  0,00s user 0,00s system 79% cpu 0,002 total
```

Comment: I also tried to put it inside a `for-loop` and see if adding `0`s has any effect on it, but it does not. Anything below `0.001` does not work...

Comment: so, that's 0.0000000001s == 0.1 ns by the way. Measurement equipment with a timing accuracy of that is ... expensive. And it makes no sense whatsoever, physically, inside a computer running Linux

Comment: Considering trying to make a general-purpose computer sleep for a tenth of a nanosecond makes not sense, what are the durations you are *actually* considering? What are you trying to **do** in the bigger picture.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I know it doesn't make any sense for a computer to measure this precisely. And what am I trying to do? As said in the question, my goal is to sleep less than 1ms. And I also know, all those extra 0's may be a bit exaggerated ^^

Comment: So then let's remove them to not open up a different question than you were meaning to ask! Timing a wait that can't be done if not the same as timing one that is absolutely technically possible.

Comment: @MarcusMüller feel free to edit the question if you think it is necessary, but I think it is fine (not perfect) as it is right now, since the question and the text indicates what I want to know. Only the example I have given isn't perfect, but that is, as I said before, an exaggeration ^^

Comment: Done! Note that I'm still confused about your use case: sleeping for sub-milliseconds within a program in a language that is compiled or runs in an optimized interpreter makes sense in *some* applications (if you're doing that, chances are high you should be doing something else but wait, but: different topic). But you're starting processes from a shell, or at least force the shell to do a lookup on a built-in `sleep` function; an operation inherently so slow and so uncertain in overhead that these short waits simply just are (nearly or fully) negligible compared to the overhead.

Comment: My guy no what have you done with the question xDDD I agreed to remove some 0's and not to change it to the **Scientific Notation**... I am gonna change it myself, but thanks I learned something new :)

Comment: Believe me I was as surprised as you that that worked!

Comment: At least try with a shell where sleep is builtin. But even there, that short  durations won't make sense. Try for instance `strace -ttTfe /sleep ksh93 -c 'for ((i=0;i<10;i++)) { printf "printf says %(%T.%N)T\n" now; sleep 0.000001; }'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sleep` typically use the `nanosleep(2)` syscall. But despite this syscall has an high precision parameter, the actual precision will depend of the timers used by Linux.

Typically, a Linux kernel is compiled with the `CONFIG_HZ=250` option. (See `/boot/config-...`).

An extension `CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS` can improve the accuracy. See https://elinux.org/High_Resolution_Timers

There where an old behaviour with a busy waiting, but not in nowadays kernel:

> ```
>   In  order  to  support  applications requiring much more precise pauses
>   (e.g., in order to control some  time-critical  hardware),  nanosleep()
>   would  handle  pauses  of up to 2 milliseconds by busy waiting with mi‐
>   crosecond precision when called from a thread scheduled under  a  real-
>   time  policy  like  SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR.  This special extension was
>   removed in kernel 2.5.39, and is thus not available in Linux 2.6.0  and
>   later kernels.
> ```

Note also that, forking a process and load a `sleep` program takes some time. On my system, I have:

```
time sleep 0.000

real    0m0,007s
user    0m0,001s
sys     0m0,006s
```

Comment: Really interesting, thanks. Where did you learn about this? :)

Comment: I have added some words about the actual time spend running `sleep` even with 0ms...

Comment: as said the accurracy of `time` is way way way less than that of the underlying sycall, because it needs to launch a process, which looks for an executable file, loads that file, jumps to its initialization code, which reserves memory, opens iostreams, looks for libraries, jumps to the starting function, the actually sleeps, then finishes, then typically closes all standard streams, and finally returns from the execution of that process, which then the `time` process needs to notice. Timing submillisecond sleep calls using a command line tool is like trying to measure the weight of feathers by

Comment: … taking a feather and counting how many trucks you need to carry that feather.

Comment: @Pixelbog the syscall use is in the code (on Debian `apt-get source coreutils` fetch the code). I had the design of a UNIX kernel in mind and know how to search the `CONFIG_HZ` option, but it may be obsolete with `CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS` And a `time sleep 0.000` shows me that it is not with an external command you will be able to do something which is sensible. Note also that syscalls are not "simple" functions. There are more things under the hood (interrupt handling, process handling, restoring the context...) then you shouldn't expect a reactivity comparable with a simple function call.